# Itinerary suggestions for a weeklong trip along New York and Vermont Borders

Tags: touring, planning

I'm starting to plan a weeklong trip in July in Northen New York/Central Vermont. I want to find a place where I could establish a basecamp: set up my tent and leave my car, and then bicycle different 50-ish mile loops every day. Maybe mix it up a little with a good day hike as well.

I've never been to this area before, so I'm a little unsure of good options. So far the following areas look appealing:

- [State Bike Route 9](https://www.dot.ny.gov/portal/pls/portal/MEXIS_APP.DYN_BIKE_TRAIL_DETAIL_MAIN.show?p_arg_names=p_trail_id&p_arg_values=145) [near Ticonderoga](http://www.mapmyride.com/us/ticonderoga-ny/). Perhaps into Green Mountain National Forest.
- [In Adirondack Park](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1OpBrDmV5j2-GuOlpVIvnP6-ltvE&hl=en_US) - Maybe basecamp near Indian Lake ([more routes highlighted](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1KZIfTT4faow97PCAkyedj5HJ6hs&hl=en_US)).

If anyone knows of 'must see' or 'must avoid' areas, I'd really appreciate a heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not central Vermont but I can vouch for the routes in [this PDF](http://www.nvda.net/files/cyclingthekingdom070413.pdf) in the Northeast Kingdom. I did a modified version of the "Around the Block" ride and threw in some of the many gravel roads in the region (and across Vermont) that make for superb touring routes.

Comment: that's a bit further east than I was thinking, but it looks super helpful. I may have to stray a bit further east. Thanks!